# Can't determine CSS' transform scale starting point

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dom

Using React, I have a collection of images of which transforms to one when a specific image is selected. I have an transform animation to transition the state from many images to one.

On click of an image I am passing through the original x,y coordinates, then subtracting offset values from existing margin and header to move the single image to the new spot. This works fine, however, once I scale the image .5  from 150px to 300px during the transformation the x,y coordinates are slightly off.

The inline css here can be found in the render function. Changing the SingleImage's height and width to 150px and scale to `1` in setState line 81 will show the problem.

[Example with no scaling](https://codepen.io/nickjsdevelope1/pen/moyqVb?editors=0110)
[Example with .5 scaling from 150px to 300px with undetermined offset](https://codepen.io/nickjsdevelope1/pen/BbyYpE?editors=0110)

```
  const a = keyframes`
      from { transform:  translate( ${this.state.cssTransform.x - 12}px, ${this.state.cssTransform.y-72}px) scale(${this.state.cssTransform.scale});                   
      }
    `

    const SingleImage = styled.div`
       animation: ${a}  2.0s;
       height:300px !important;
       width:300px !important;
    `
```

Once again, between the 2 I'm not sure why there is a new offset. Its seems to be around 75px.  My suspicion, is that the new image is scaling down half of 300px to 150px, then the translate pixels are being applied skewing it?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to subtract an addition 75px from each x and y offset. As the image scales down originally from 300 to 150px, 75px is subtracted from each side, then the transform is being applied.

Comment: did you try to simply set the transform-origin to top? it would be easier that dealing with offsets

Comment: I'm not sure I understand,  top and Y also hold the same values.